# What am I doing wrong? SQL aggregate

Tags: sql, aggregate

I am using MS Access (north wind database), when I try to run the bottom query I get the following error.

> Your query does not include the specified expession 'unit price *
>   quantity' as part of an aggregate function.

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong:

[image]

```
Select productid, unitprice * quantity AS total_price, count (orderid) as total_count
FROM [order details]
GROUP BY productid, price
```

Comment: Exactly as the error says, you didn't add `unitprice * quantity` into your aggregate function `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this. In group by statements, you can only include grouped columns along with Sum, Count etc. These are known as "Aggregate functions".

Any column that is not an aggregate function (or where or expression) needs to be listed in group by.

I assume you wish to do this:

```
Select productid, Count (orderid) as total_count, Sum (unitprice * quantity) AS total_price
FROM [order details]
GROUP BY productid
```